# How to access properly to javascript class values

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I was setting up a class constructor for handling my database, I did, but on the road I got some doubts about javascript's behavior.

To better understand the problem I reduced everything to its minimal expression. Here is the core:

**name.js**

```
class Name {
    constructor(){
        this.value = 'mo'
    }
    setName(){
        this.value = 'moom'
    }
}

export default new Name()
```

**sayName.js**

```
import name from './name'

const outsideName = name.value

function sayName(){
    const insideName = name.value
    console.log(insideName) // => moon
    console.log(outsideName) // => mo
}

export default sayName
```

**index.js**

```
import name from './name'
import sayName from './sayName'

name.setName()
sayName()
```

I was expecting to get the same output value from the console(moon).
Why are the outputs from the console different(mo !=== moon)?
I'd appreciate it if you could help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You create an instance of Name
2. You copy the value of its name property (mo) to `outsideName`
3. You call `name.setName()` which changes the value of its `name` property to moon.
4. You log the value of its `name` property.
5. You log the value of `outsideName`

Since you never change `outsideName` after step 2, it doesn't change.

---

> I reduced everything to its minimal expression.

You can reduce it further.

```js
let object = { foo: 1 };
let value = object.foo;
object.foo = 2;
console.log( object.foo, value);
```

Comment: @MoOn — That's what your code already does. That's what this answer already describes.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. What about calling `name.setName()` before `sayName`. Doesn't it update the value of name? How I can get it work and get the same output in console?

Comment: It does update name, that is why `console.log(insideName)` logs moon and not mo. If you want `outsideName` to be updated so it is the same then you need to write code to update `outsideName`.

Comment: Now I see how it goes. But I still have a doubt. How can I keep the value of the name updated? I would like to request this instance from other files and get the updated value. Like a store. Thanks for your input @Quentin.